# Combine configure() + hasAuthority() and PreAuthorize

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I configured my app like this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .anonymous().principal("guest").authorities("GUEST_ROLE")
    .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
    .and()
    .formLogin();
}
```

And one of my controllers in "/admin/" is defined with

```
@PreAuthorize("@securityService.hasPermission('SALEPOINT', #id)")
```

But if a user is not "ADMIN" but is ok with my securityService.hasPermission, it is allowed. Actually, I would like hasAuthority("ADMIN") to be checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove `.antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")` from configuration because it get's overwritten by the annotation `@PreAuthorize`

Then add the following logic inside the `@PreAuthorize` annotation by making it

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN') AND @securityService.hasPermission('SALEPOINT', #id)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it does not test the hasAuthority("ADMIN") above when I try.

Comment: @Florent06 try with `.antMatchers("**/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")` maybe the path doesn't correctly match. Try this to verify

Comment: unfortunately same result

Comment: @Florent06 please post your complete controller to examine the reason

Comment: Thanks for update. Isn't it possible to define global authorization for ADMINS like I think I did?

Comment: `@PreAuthorize` and `hasAthority()` in global config are the same configurations behind the scene. So IMO @PreAuthorize as more specific one overwrittes the global config of `hasAuthority()`. So in your current situation you must define everything inside `@PreAuthorize`